# Redis over socks proxy

Tags: java, nginx, redis, proxy, squid

I'm using a java application through following socks proxy:

```
-DsocksProxyHost=localhost
-DsocksProxyPort=1337
```

It's works partially, it connects to MySQL database successfully, but doesn't connect to Redis:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host xxx.amazonaws.com:6379
```

How can I connect to Redis in my application using proxy?
**Can i use squid or nginx to force connection to redis host through this proxy?**
Any other idea to force this connection?